# Unable to load webextension in firefox using python selenium

Tags: selenium, web, driver

Hi I am seeing this issue when I try to load a Firefox webextension using Python Selenium:

> selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.AddonFormatError: ("[Errno 2] No such
>    file or directory: 'c:\\users\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpr
>   wj4ed.xxx.xpi\\install.rdf'", )

## Code is as below

```
from selenium import webdriver

extn_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxx\xxx.xpi"
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.add_extension(extn_path)
self.browser=webdriver.Firefox(profile,executable_path='xxx\geckodriver.exe')
```

## Versions used

- Selenium 3.12
- Gecko v.0.20
- Firefox- 60

Can anyone let me know why I am facing this issue. I did see that many people are facing this issue and it's mentioned that it's a known issue but with latest Selenium and Gecko driver issue it is expected to be resolved.

However, I don't see it working. Any tips or inputs.

Answer (score 0):

can you try double front slash instead one single  front slash inside your path

Comment: Yes I have tried with double slash as well.I have ensured the value of  extn_path" through debugger.Its "C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxx\xxx.xpi"

Comment: Ok sometimes it will pick double back slash instead of double front slash . Try that one too